# How to insert a space after pifont symbol?

Tags: spacing, symbols

I've inserted a "cross" (`\ding{55}`) from package `pifont` in a text but I can't insert a space after it, Latex ignores the space from the source code. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Edit:

There was some missing information. I'm using `\newcommand`. Here is a * not * working example ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cross}{\ding{55}}
\begin{document}
\cross a

\cross. a

\cross . a
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with **pifont**, but rather with the general problem of spaces after commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

In relation to your edit use `xspace`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont,xspace}
\newcommand{\cross}{\ding{55}\xspace}
\begin{document}
\cross a

\cross. a

\cross . a
\end{document}
```

Why don't you get any space?

This works well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\ding{55} a

\ding{55}. a

\ding{55} . a
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right. The space should be there! I'll delete my answer while the OP answers your question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: `xspace` was also my first try (see my revision) ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately there was some important missing information. Please, see the edit.

Comment: Great! Worked with `\xspace`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The "problem" that you encountered with the space has nothing to do with pifont or any other package.  In general, with any command, you have to tell TeX/LaTeX where the command has ended.  If you have a character that cannot be part of a command (like the brackets, the numbers etc, unless you change their default `\catcode`), occurence of such a character would automatically tell TeX/LaTeX that the command has ended before this character.  This happens in the example

```
\cross.A
```

But if you write

```
\cross A
```

then TeX/LaTeX does not know that the command has ended after you wrote "`\cross`".  It goes forward, and sees a blank space, and then it knows that the command has ended.  After that, there is no space, so it does not separate the cross and the letter A.  If you write

```
{\cross} A
```

you will obtain a space.  Or if you write

```
\cross{} A
```

that will also do.  There is no need to use packages for such simple things.